# String equals and == with String concatenation

Tags: java, string, equals, string-concatenation

I am trying to understand the String concatenation with the output of String compare. To be clear, i have the class to compare two strings using == and equals. I am trying to concat the output of == and equals() to a string. The output of equals() concats, but the output of == **does not** concat. Using boxing feature of java, the boolean concatenated with  string will contact. Both equals and == returns boolean to my knowledge. So why is this difference? Can anyone explain on this?

```
public class StringHandler {

    public void compareStrings() {
        String s1 = new String("jai");
        String s2 = "jai";
        String s3 = "jai";
        System.out.println("Object and literal compare by double equal to :: "
                + s1 == s2);
        System.out.println("Object and literal compare by equals :: "
                + s1.equals(s2));
        System.out
                .println("Literal comparing by double equal to :: " + s2 == s3);
        System.out.println("Literal comparing by equals :: " + s2.equals(s3));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringHandler sHandler = new StringHandler();
        sHandler.compareStrings();
    }
}
```

**output**

```
false
Object and literal compare by equals :: true
false
Literal compareing by equals :: true
```

**Update: Answer**

Without parenthesis for s1==s2, the JVM compares the string as "Object and literal compare by double equal to :: jai" == "jai" and the result is **false**. So the actual content in sysout is not printed. When parenthesis is added the JVM compares the string as "jai" == "jai" and the result is

`Object and literal compare by double equal to :: true`

Comment: Didn't it strike you as significant that the string was "swallowed"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do

```
System.out.println("Object and literal compare by double equal to :: "
            + s1 == s2);
```

you are first concatenating the string `"Object and literal compare by double equal to :: "` with the string `s1`, which will give

```
"Object and literal compare by double equal to :: jai"
```

then, you are checking if this string is the same object (same reference) than `s2`:

```
"Object and literal compare by double equal to :: jai" == "jai"
```

which will be `false` (the output will be `false`).

In other words, it's because **operators precedence**. One way to "manipulate" operators precedende is to use parentheses. The operations inside parentheses will be parsed first:

```
System.out.println("Object and literal compare by double equal to :: " + (s1 == s2));
```

Answer (score 5):

Add parentheses!

```
  System.out.println("Object and literal compare by double equal to :: " +
                     (s1 == s2));
```

PLus and other arithmetic ops have higher priority than comparison ops. Using '+' for concat  doesn't change that.

Answer (score 4):

**problem:**

```
+ s2 == s3
```

`+` sign has higher precedence than `==` so it will execute(`append`) it first before executing the `==` thus giving you only `"false"`

You need to put parenthesis so it will check for the result of your string compare.

also `parenthesis` has higher [precedence](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) than `+` sign to it will compare the string first before appending it to the string.

**sample**:

```
 System.out.println("Object and literal compare by double equal to :: " + (s1==s2));
    System.out.println("Object and literal compare by equals :: " + (s1.equals(s2)));
    System.out.println("Literal compareing by double equal to :: " + (s2 == s3));
    System.out.println("Literal compareing by equals :: " + (s2.equals(s3)));
```

**operator precedence:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an order of operations issue. It's being interpreted as follows (parentheses added) :

```
System.out.println(("Object and literal compare by double equal to :: " + s1)  == s2);
System.out.println("Object and literal compare by equals :: " + (s1.equals(s2)) );
System.out.println(("Literal compareing by double equal to :: " + s2)  == s3);
System.out.println("Literal compareing by equals :: " + (s2.equals(s3)) );
```